# Multiple QRadioButton error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qradiobutton

I'm using PyQt5 to create a program. I created 3 Radio Buttons, but when I check the first button and check the second button after that. The program will run both of the functions which are connected to these buttons. How I can make it only run the function which is connected to that button. Thanks.

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Program, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_APIManager()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.show()
    self.ui.add_btn.toggled.connect(self.start)
    self.ui.check_btn.toggled.connect(self.start)
    self.ui.delete_btn.toggled.connect(self.start)

def start(self):
    if self.ui.add_btn.isChecked():
        self.ui.third_lbl.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.first_lbl.setText('Tool name')
        self.ui.second_lbl.setText('ID')
        self.ui.third_lbl.setText('Username')
        self.ui.action_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_user)

    elif self.ui.check_btn.isChecked():
        self.ui.first_lbl.setText('Type of search')
        self.ui.second_lbl.setText('Keyword')
        self.ui.third_lbl.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.action_btn.clicked.connect(self.check_user)

    elif self.ui.delete_btn.isChecked():
        self.ui.first_lbl.setText('Type of search')
        self.ui.second_lbl.setText('Keyword')
        self.ui.third_lbl.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.action_btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt signals can have multiple slots attached to them. Every time you click a button the `start` function is adding another connection to the `action_button.clicked` signal.

You will need to disconnect any existing slots from the signal first to achieve the desired behaviour. You can disconnect everything from `self.ui.action_btn` all at once by calling its [`disconnect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) function.

Rather than trying to reassign the roles of the GUI elements you have created, you would be better off creating separate widgets containing the elements for each checkbox state and switching between them. You might find [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for answer but where I can put `self.ui.action_btn.disconnect()`.
I tried to add below `self.ui.action_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_user)` but when I clicked Ok button, nothing happen.

Comment: You can place it right at the beginning of the `start` function in your example.

Comment: You need to add it before you connect the new slot, or else it will remove that connection too.